# Переход к  первому элементу следующего блока

Tags: jquery

Есть простой список со вложенными картинками.

```
<ul>

<li>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
<div class="wrapper"<img></div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на последнюю картинку в <li> осуществлялся переход к первой картинке следующего <li>.

[ДЕМО](http://jsbin.com/nawayala/6/edit)

Скрипт перехода по картинкам, работает пока только в пределах одного <li>

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var clicked;

$('.wrapper').click(function(){

clicked = $(this);
clicked.find('img').fadeOut().trigger('click');
});

$('button.next').click(function(){
  clicked.next().find('img').fadeOut().trigger('click');

   }); 
   });
```

Нигде не могу найти ответ уже несколько недель в интернете! В пределах одного родителя понятно, а как перейти к следующему родителю, использую переменную, указанную в коде?
Благодарю заранее.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nawayala/8/edit

Comment: likerRr, большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли! Как только позволит репутация, обязательно верну плюсик.

Comment: likerRr, скажите, пожалуйста, а как правильно написать значение  length у кнопки "prev". Пробую код 
if ((allImg.length=0) == imgIndex) {
    clicked = clicked.parent().prev().find('.wrapper').eq(2);

однако он как-то странно работает, через раз. Как мне показать программе, что мне нужен первый дочерний блок?
Большое спасибо!