# Не работает обращение к first-child  в js

Tags: jquery

В [этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/324727/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) я задавала вопрос, как перейти к первому элементу следующего блока. Пользуясь случаем, хочу еще раз поблагодарить пользователя [likerRr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5625/likerrr) который написал рабочее решение. Для проекта нужна еще кнопка prev.

[ДЕМО](http://jsbin.com/nawayala/10/edit)

Я никак не могу понять, почему, если задать 
allImg[0]
который указывает на first-child  (то есть первое изображение в списке), условие не работает?

Заранее благодарю за любую подсказку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы сравниваете элемент с числом.

allImg[0] это DOM элемент, а imgIndex - число.

сделайте лучше проверку в условии

```
if (curImg.is(allImg.first()) {/*....*/}
```

вообще вы бы демку как нить переделали, чтобы нагляднее все показывалось, а-то что-то куда-то исчезает, что произошло - непонятно.... просто класс присваивайте текущей картинке, а у других убирайте (у активной например нарисуйте толстую рамку в css).

Comment: eicto, большое спасибо! Прошу прощения за неясный код, обновила его с красной рамкой на активном элементе и добавила  
if (curImg.is(allImg.last()))
соответственно в кнопку next. 
Кнопка prev заработала! Только никак не могу понять, почему, если второй раз нажать кнопку next, выделяется сразу последний элемент в первом списке, а не первый. И если выделить все элементы кнопкой next, то сбросить класс кнопкой prev уже не получается. Это может быть из-за того, что я неправильно указала в кнопке prev номер элемента - .eq(2)?
В адаптивной версии у меня останется только одна картинка в списке.

Comment: ДЕМО - http://jsbin.com/nawayala/12/edit

Comment: вот я немного переделал, чтобы код был понятнее :) и чтобы работало http://jsbin.com/viwumada/2/edit не знаю, что у вас там было, всё было слишком запутано.

Comment: ещё упрощение http://jsbin.com/viwumada/4/edit

Comment: eicto, огромное спасибо! Скрипт в проект встал идеально. Такую виртуозную! логику, я конечно, не смогла бы придумать). Я прочитала не один десяток туториалов, наших и зарубежных, но такого не встречала. Еще раз большое спасибо!